# Mutiple Content Editable binding inside string using knockout

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, contenteditable

I'm having a string that contains many editable region, please consider this string

```
 var str = "Regular ... are patterns used to match character .... in strings. In ..., regular expressions are also objects."
```

editable regions are contains ('...'), I want to make that places editable. means i want inject a editable content inside that string. I would like to use knockout for this purpose. I've referred the niemeyer's about content editable using knockout. can anyone suggest me a better way to achieve this. this my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aroor/QUEkv/9/)

```
         ko.bindingHandlers.editableContent = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

            $(element).css({ "background-color": "#ff77ee", "margin-left": "-2px", "letter-spacing": "0.05"});

            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keyup", function() {
                var modelValue = valueAccessor();
                var elementValue = element.innerHTML;
                if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modelValue)) {
                    modelValue(elementValue);
                }
                else { //handle non-observable one-way binding
                    var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
                    if (allBindings['_ko_property_writers'] && allBindings['_ko_property_writers'].editableContent) allBindings['_ko_property_writers'].editableContent(elementValue);
                }
            })
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || "";
            element.innerHTML = value;
        }
    };




    ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var fulltext = valueAccessor();

            element.appendChild(div);

            div.innerHTML = fulltext().replace(/\.\.\./g, "<span data-bind = 'editableContent : editedText' contenteditable='true'></span>");

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel,div);


        },

        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var viewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.fullText = ko.observable('Regular ... are patterns used to match character .... in strings. In ..., regular expressions are also objects.');
            self.editedText = ko.observable('...');

        }

        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that each editableContent binding is bound against the same observable, so they are updating each other.

Here is a quick attempt at splitting the text into pieces and adding individual observables for each separate contenteditable.

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var div = document.createElement("div"),
                fulltext = valueAccessor(),
                split = fulltext().split(/\.\.\./g),
                span, editable, editableSpan, pieces = [];

            element.appendChild(div);

            //loop through each pieces and add text and editable content
            for (var i = 0, j = split.length; i < j; i++) {
              //create a span for the fixed content
              span = document.createElement("span");
              span.innerHTML = split[i];

              //keep track of each piece, so we can later put them back together to update original
              pieces.push(split[i]);
              div.appendChild(span);

              //add editable content between the pieces, except at the end
              if (i < split.length - 1) {
                editable = ko.observable("...");
                editableSpan = document.createElement("span");
                pieces.push(editable);
                div.appendChild(editableSpan);
                ko.applyBindingsToNode(editableSpan, { editableContent: editable });
              }

            }

            //update the original observable with the current value
            ko.computed({
                read: function() {
                    var result = "";
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(pieces, function(piece) {
                       result += ko.utils.unwrapObservable(piece); 
                    });

                    valueAccessor()(result);
                },
                disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
            });

            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
    };
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/8CkLn/

Note that this handles updating the original observable based on edits, but would not handle updating the content editable blocks, if you updated the original observable in another way.

Comment: Thank you Ryan.! It worked perfectly. I tried to split the text and insert the observable dynamically It didn't worked. after i tried your code it worked charm. In order to track the content editable block changes I'll try to write the code under the update method.

Comment: @Ryan in order to get value from the content editable block, do i have to define that in the main view model as observable? I was trying to get the value from the block it doesn't working. please help me

Comment: Are we talking about the resulting value of all of the pieces?  That part should be getting updated (in the binding I listed) as long as the original value is an observable.

Comment: If i want to get the content editable block data and save into to DB(not the whole resulting pieces), Do I've to declare that in the main view model. I'm currently doing on that i'll post the fiddle soon. there is an issue with the IE 7 and 8 array split function it will ignore the empty string value if full text contains the text like this "Regular ... are patterns used to match character .... in strings...".

Comment: @Ryan. I've created a new fiddle with tracking the editable block changes. http://jsfiddle.net/aroor/Bda4f/1/ could you please have a look on it? Is that an efficient way?thanks

Comment: This last fiddle doesn't seem to be working for me.  Sorry, didn't get to look into it further.

Comment: Now I've updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/aroor/Bda4f/4/ can you have a look again?

Comment: @ryan do you have time to look at those code?Now I've updated the fiddle. if there is any efficient way to achieve that?